# How to describe legacy table one-to-many connection with Sequelize models object?

Tags: orm, sequelize.js, one-to-many, belongs-to, has-one

I'm trying to use [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/) with legacy table and stuck how to define [one-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)) connection of my database in Sequelize`s model.

I have the following tables:

**pesons**:

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id |  name   | language_id |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 | Anatoly |           1 |
|  2 | Roman   |           2 |
|  3 | Pavel   |           1 |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

and

**languages**:

```
+----+---------+
| id |  value  |
+----+---------+
|  1 | English |
|  2 | Hebrew  |
|  3 | Russian |
+----+---------+
```

Like you can see, every `Person` can know one `Language` but same `Language` can be known by different `Persons`.

```
var Person = sequelize.define('person', {
    id : {
        field: 'id',
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name : {
        field: 'name',
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    }
},{
    tableName: 'persons',
    timestamps: false
});


var Language = sequelize.define('language', {
    id : {
        field: 'id',
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    value : {
        field: 'value',
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    }
},{
    tableName: 'languages',
    timestamps: false
})
```

According to official manual: [Difference between HasOne and BelongsTo](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#difference-between-hasone-and-belongsto)

> When information about association is present in source model we can
>   use belongsTo.

I need to define relations between `Person` and `Language` as:

```
Person.belongsTo(Language);
```

But it looks wrong to me and counter intuitive, so I'd like to get some clarification from somebody.

P.S. For the sake of clarity, I've never used any ORM before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In usual case it would be every Person can know many Language but same Language can be known by different Persons

so there is many to many association so we do many to many association
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#nm

But for your use case kindly rephrase your scentence as

Languages has many persons (users), So here comes one to many association, there is no part of has one association.

belongs to and has many must be used in pairs, since they are counter parts

So first

```
Language.hasMany(Person)
```

The orm will add all the essential instance and class method to languages so that you can easily query, add and delete a person to a language.

Second part

```
Person.belongsTo(Language)
```

The orm will add all the essential instance and class method to Persons so that you can easily query, add and delete a Language to a person.

Comment: So, I need both `Language.hasMany(Person)`, and `Person.belongsTo(Language) ` to cause it work?

Comment: Yes, for eg if you do not do Language.hasMany(Person) then you wont be able to do language.getPersons()